# ¿Contar número de enlaces con ruta específica?

Tags: javascript, dom

> A partir de la página web proporcionada y utilizando las funciones
>   DOM, mostrar por pantalla la siguiente información:
>
> **Numero de enlaces que enlazan a http://prueba**

Código HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Ejercicio 14 - DOM básico</title>

</head>

<body style="">

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <a href="http://prueba/">consectetuer adipiscing elit</a>
        . Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi.
        <a href="http://prueba2/">Fusce porta</a>
        . Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque. Donec lacus neque, vehicula in, eleifend vitae, venenatis ac, felis. Donec arcu. Nam sed tortor nec ipsum aliquam ullamcorper. Duis accumsan metus eu urna. Aenean vitae enim. Integer lacus. Vestibulum venenatis erat eu odio. Praesent id metus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Aenean at nisl. Maecenas egestas dapibus odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin consequat auctor diam.
        <a href="http://prueba/">Ut bibendum blandit est</a>
        . Curabitur vestibulum. Nunc malesuada porttitor sapien. Aenean a lacus et metus venenatis porta. Suspendisse cursus, sem non dapibus tincidunt, lorem magna porttitor felis, id sodales dolor dolor sed urna. Sed rutrum nulla vitae tellus. Sed quis eros nec lectus tempor lacinia. Aliquam nec lectus nec neque aliquet dictum. Etiam
        <a href="http://prueba3/">consequat sem quis massa</a>
        . Donec aliquam euismod diam. In magna massa, mattis id, pellentesque sit amet, porta sit amet, lectus. Curabitur posuere. Aliquam in elit. Fusce condimentum, arcu in scelerisque lobortis, ante arcu scelerisque mi, at cursus mi risus sed tellus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Donec sagittis, nibh nec ullamcorper tristique, pede velit feugiat massa, at sollicitudin justo tellus vitae justo. Vestibulum aliquet, nulla sit amet imperdiet suscipit, nunc erat laoreet est, a
        <a href="http://prueba/">aliquam leo odio sed sem</a>
        . Quisque eget eros vehicula diam euismod tristique. Ut dui. Donec in metus sed risus laoreet sollicitudin. Proin et nisi non arcu sodales hendrerit. In sem. Cras id augue eu lorem dictum interdum. Donec pretium. Proin
        <a href="http://prueba4/">egestas</a>
        adipiscing ligula. Duis iaculis laoreet turpis. Mauris mollis est sit amet diam. Curabitur hendrerit, eros quis malesuada tristique, ipsum odio euismod tortor, a vestibulum nisl mi at odio.
        <a href="http://prueba5/">Sed non lectus non est pellentesque</a>
        auctor.
    </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Código Javascript

```
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var cont = 0;
for (var i in enlaces) {
    if (enlaces[i].src.substr(0,13) == "http://prueba") {
        cont++;
    }
}
console.log("Cantidad de enlaces que apuntan a: http://prueba es" + cont);
```

Lamentablemente no me funciona el código que he creado, pueden guiarme a ver si logro hallar la solución?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estabas cerca:

```js
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var enlacePrueba = "http://prueba/";
var cont = 0;
enlaces.forEach(function(element) {
    if (element.href == enlacePrueba) {
        cont++;
    }
});
console.log("Cantidad de enlaces que apuntan a: " + enlacePrueba + " es " + cont);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Ejercicio 14 - DOM básico</title>

</head>

<body style="">

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <a href="http://prueba/">consectetuer adipiscing elit</a>
        . Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi.
        <a href="http://prueba2/">Fusce porta</a>
        . Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque. Donec lacus neque, vehicula in, eleifend vitae, venenatis ac, felis. Donec arcu. Nam sed tortor nec ipsum aliquam ullamcorper. Duis accumsan metus eu urna. Aenean vitae enim. Integer lacus. Vestibulum venenatis erat eu odio. Praesent id metus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Aenean at nisl. Maecenas egestas dapibus odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin consequat auctor diam.
        <a href="http://prueba/">Ut bibendum blandit est</a>
        . Curabitur vestibulum. Nunc malesuada porttitor sapien. Aenean a lacus et metus venenatis porta. Suspendisse cursus, sem non dapibus tincidunt, lorem magna porttitor felis, id sodales dolor dolor sed urna. Sed rutrum nulla vitae tellus. Sed quis eros nec lectus tempor lacinia. Aliquam nec lectus nec neque aliquet dictum. Etiam
        <a href="http://prueba3/">consequat sem quis massa</a>
        . Donec aliquam euismod diam. In magna massa, mattis id, pellentesque sit amet, porta sit amet, lectus. Curabitur posuere. Aliquam in elit. Fusce condimentum, arcu in scelerisque lobortis, ante arcu scelerisque mi, at cursus mi risus sed tellus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Donec sagittis, nibh nec ullamcorper tristique, pede velit feugiat massa, at sollicitudin justo tellus vitae justo. Vestibulum aliquet, nulla sit amet imperdiet suscipit, nunc erat laoreet est, a
        <a href="http://prueba/">aliquam leo odio sed sem</a>
        . Quisque eget eros vehicula diam euismod tristique. Ut dui. Donec in metus sed risus laoreet sollicitudin. Proin et nisi non arcu sodales hendrerit. In sem. Cras id augue eu lorem dictum interdum. Donec pretium. Proin
        <a href="http://prueba4/">egestas</a>
        adipiscing ligula. Duis iaculis laoreet turpis. Mauris mollis est sit amet diam. Curabitur hendrerit, eros quis malesuada tristique, ipsum odio euismod tortor, a vestibulum nisl mi at odio.
        <a href="http://prueba5/">Sed non lectus non est pellentesque</a>
        auctor.
    </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Lo que estoy haciendo simplemente es usar el método `forEach` para iterar sobre cada enlace. Luego preguntar si el atributo `href` es igual a lo que quieres buscar, si es así, incrementar el contador y finalmente mostrarlo.

## ¿Por qué no estaba funcionando tu código?

```js
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var cont = 0;
for (var i in enlaces) {
    console.log(i);
    console.log(enlaces[i].src);
    console.log(enlaces[i].href);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Ejercicio 14 - DOM básico</title>

</head>

<body style="">

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <a href="http://prueba/">consectetuer adipiscing elit</a>
        . Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi.
        <a href="http://prueba2/">Fusce porta</a>
        . Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque. Donec lacus neque, vehicula in, eleifend vitae, venenatis ac, felis. Donec arcu. Nam sed tortor nec ipsum aliquam ullamcorper. Duis accumsan metus eu urna. Aenean vitae enim. Integer lacus. Vestibulum venenatis erat eu odio. Praesent id metus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Aenean at nisl. Maecenas egestas dapibus odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin consequat auctor diam.
        <a href="http://prueba/">Ut bibendum blandit est</a>
        . Curabitur vestibulum. Nunc malesuada porttitor sapien. Aenean a lacus et metus venenatis porta. Suspendisse cursus, sem non dapibus tincidunt, lorem magna porttitor felis, id sodales dolor dolor sed urna. Sed rutrum nulla vitae tellus. Sed quis eros nec lectus tempor lacinia. Aliquam nec lectus nec neque aliquet dictum. Etiam
        <a href="http://prueba3/">consequat sem quis massa</a>
        . Donec aliquam euismod diam. In magna massa, mattis id, pellentesque sit amet, porta sit amet, lectus. Curabitur posuere. Aliquam in elit. Fusce condimentum, arcu in scelerisque lobortis, ante arcu scelerisque mi, at cursus mi risus sed tellus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Donec sagittis, nibh nec ullamcorper tristique, pede velit feugiat massa, at sollicitudin justo tellus vitae justo. Vestibulum aliquet, nulla sit amet imperdiet suscipit, nunc erat laoreet est, a
        <a href="http://prueba/">aliquam leo odio sed sem</a>
        . Quisque eget eros vehicula diam euismod tristique. Ut dui. Donec in metus sed risus laoreet sollicitudin. Proin et nisi non arcu sodales hendrerit. In sem. Cras id augue eu lorem dictum interdum. Donec pretium. Proin
        <a href="http://prueba4/">egestas</a>
        adipiscing ligula. Duis iaculis laoreet turpis. Mauris mollis est sit amet diam. Curabitur hendrerit, eros quis malesuada tristique, ipsum odio euismod tortor, a vestibulum nisl mi at odio.
        <a href="http://prueba5/">Sed non lectus non est pellentesque</a>
        auctor.
    </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

- Al iterar haciendo `i in enlaces`, estás iterando las propiedades, no los enlaces. Si ves el `console.log(i)` he puesto, verás algo como esto:

  ```
  0
  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  length
  item
  entries
  forEach
  keys
  values
  ```
- La propiedad `src` no existe, como podrás comprobar en el `console.log(enlaces[i].src)` que he agregado.
- Lo correcto sería usar la propiedad `href` como lo muestra el `console.log(enlaces[i].href)` pero como puedes ver, no todos tienen esa propiedad (como los métodos `forEach`, `keys`, `values`, etc.)
- Si quisieras hacerlo de esta forma, tendrías que preguntar si, efectivamente, lo que estás iterando tiene una propiedad `href`, si es así recién puedes comparar y aumentar el contador.

Haciéndolo a tu forma, tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```js
var enlaces = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var enlacePrueba = "http://prueba/";
var cont = 0;
for (var i in enlaces) {
    if (enlaces[i].href != undefined && enlaces[i].href == enlacePrueba) {
        cont++;
    }
}
console.log("Cantidad de enlaces que apuntan a: " + enlacePrueba + " es " + cont);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

    <title>Ejercicio 14 - DOM básico</title>

</head>

<body style="">

    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
        <a href="http://prueba/">consectetuer adipiscing elit</a>
        . Sed mattis enim vitae orci. Phasellus libero. Maecenas nisl arcu, consequat congue, commodo nec, commodo ultricies, turpis. Quisque sapien nunc, posuere vitae, rutrum et, luctus at, pede. Pellentesque massa ante, ornare id, aliquam vitae, ultrices porttitor, pede. Nullam sit amet nisl elementum elit convallis malesuada. Phasellus magna sem, semper quis, faucibus ut, rhoncus non, mi.
        <a href="http://prueba2/">Fusce porta</a>
        . Duis pellentesque, felis eu adipiscing ullamcorper, odio urna consequat arcu, at posuere ante quam non dolor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Duis scelerisque. Donec lacus neque, vehicula in, eleifend vitae, venenatis ac, felis. Donec arcu. Nam sed tortor nec ipsum aliquam ullamcorper. Duis accumsan metus eu urna. Aenean vitae enim. Integer lacus. Vestibulum venenatis erat eu odio. Praesent id metus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Aenean at nisl. Maecenas egestas dapibus odio. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Proin consequat auctor diam.
        <a href="http://prueba/">Ut bibendum blandit est</a>
        . Curabitur vestibulum. Nunc malesuada porttitor sapien. Aenean a lacus et metus venenatis porta. Suspendisse cursus, sem non dapibus tincidunt, lorem magna porttitor felis, id sodales dolor dolor sed urna. Sed rutrum nulla vitae tellus. Sed quis eros nec lectus tempor lacinia. Aliquam nec lectus nec neque aliquet dictum. Etiam
        <a href="http://prueba3/">consequat sem quis massa</a>
        . Donec aliquam euismod diam. In magna massa, mattis id, pellentesque sit amet, porta sit amet, lectus. Curabitur posuere. Aliquam in elit. Fusce condimentum, arcu in scelerisque lobortis, ante arcu scelerisque mi, at cursus mi risus sed tellus.
    </p>

    <p>
        Donec sagittis, nibh nec ullamcorper tristique, pede velit feugiat massa, at sollicitudin justo tellus vitae justo. Vestibulum aliquet, nulla sit amet imperdiet suscipit, nunc erat laoreet est, a
        <a href="http://prueba/">aliquam leo odio sed sem</a>
        . Quisque eget eros vehicula diam euismod tristique. Ut dui. Donec in metus sed risus laoreet sollicitudin. Proin et nisi non arcu sodales hendrerit. In sem. Cras id augue eu lorem dictum interdum. Donec pretium. Proin
        <a href="http://prueba4/">egestas</a>
        adipiscing ligula. Duis iaculis laoreet turpis. Mauris mollis est sit amet diam. Curabitur hendrerit, eros quis malesuada tristique, ipsum odio euismod tortor, a vestibulum nisl mi at odio.
        <a href="http://prueba5/">Sed non lectus non est pellentesque</a>
        auctor.
    </p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="codigo.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: ¡Gracias César! ahora veo que funciona perfectamente,disculpa la molestia  pero podrías explicarme un poco que función práctica tiene "function(element)" por favor?, no he logrado captarlo aún, apenas comienzo a dar mi primeros pasos con javascript, o podrías indicarme a que tema se corresponde esa función para investigar un poco?

Comment: @PedroFumero ninguna molestia. ¿A qué te refieres con `function(element)` exactamente?

Comment: Vale César :), en el primer código que escribiste colocaste esta función: `function(element)` ¿Qué es lo que hace exactamente? Ya que según veo el parámetro que recibe no se le pasó desde ningún lugar, por eso no entiendo que hace exactamente.

Comment: @PedroFumero entiendo. El método `forEach` itera cada elemento, por lo tanto a la función le estoy pasando justamente el elemento que se está iterando para poder hacerle refenrecia dentro de la función. ¿Lo viste? Puedes usar cualquier nombre, yo le puse `element` porque me pareció lo más adecuado ya que es un elemento `<a>`.

Comment: Está desaconsejado utilizar `for...in` para recorrer listas. Lo ideal es utilizar `for...of`. Aquí ejemplos de como recorrer NodeList's utilizando ES6 : https://gist.github.com/bendc/4090e383865d81b4b684

Comment: @César ahora si lo veo! ¡Muchas gracias!